# About Mongodb: Atomic Get and Set

Tags: mongodb, atomic

I'm a Mongodb beginner, I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id": "abc",
    "names": {
        "1" : "name1",
        "2" : "name2",
        "3" : "name3"
    }
}
```

I want to use multithread add 'name4', 'name5', 'nameX'...  to "names"

My way:

- step1 : get all names
- step2 : add 'nameN' to names (names[n]='nameN')
- step3 : set new names

I know this is not atomic -_-!! so My question is How To Make It Atomic?

My another way:
add a 'version' field to document, when Get the results, record the 'version', then Set the 'names' with the 'version' like :

```
update_one({"_id": "abc", "version": currentVersion}, {$set: {"names": newNames}})
```

If it does not match the 'version', the update failed, new 'nameN' will not add to the document. I want it to success any time.

Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: `names` is an object NOT an array. So you can't do `names[n]='nameN'

Comment: @Siddharth Ajmera  Thank you, i use pymongo client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB only guarantees transaction on a document-level.

For your requirements you must guarantee the atomicity at the application-level using thread synchronization.